# How to resize object without scaling pattern in FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm wondering if there is an option to resize object without scaling its pattern in FabricJS?

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/c22hm40b/)

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/site/integrators/slackhq.png', function(img) {
  var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas()
  patternSourceCanvas.add(img)
  patternSourceCanvas.setBackgroundColor('red', patternSourceCanvas.renderAll.bind(patternSourceCanvas))
  patternSourceCanvas.setHeight(256);
  patternSourceCanvas.setWidth(256);

  var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
    source: function() {
      return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
    },
    repeat: 'no-repeat'
  })

  // create a rectangle object
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: pattern,
    width: 256,
    height: 256
  })

  // "add" rectangle onto canvas
  canvas.add(rect)

})
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this little code below. This will rescale the background pattern for you while scaling.

```
canvas.observe("object:scaling", function (e) {
    var shape = e.target;
    shape.width = shape.scaleX * shape.width;
    shape.height = shape.scaleY * shape.height;
    shape.scaleX = 1;
    shape.scaleY = 1;
});
```

Comment: Your code snippet is returning an error message, is it what was expected?

Comment: This is because fabric.js is not included in the snippet. I will try to transform it to a 'regular' code block.

Comment: @Sjoerd.Be - Try clicking the left center handle, and moving back and forth. You see the right side move as well. Also, drag all the way from left to right, and continue passed the right side slowly. You will see the line move for some reason. Does your implementation not cause this strange behavior? https://codepen.io/carter485/pen/XPowyw

Comment: Yes it does. I did not manage to solve this and I switched to an implementation of interact.js